# Validating data and reporting errors from data migration

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am customizing a complex data migration by adding custom SQL to make required changes.

For example, I have a `PurchaseOrders` table that includes a product name, but I'm changing it to be a foreign key to the `Products` table. So I need to write custom SQL set each foreign key to the ID of the matching product (this must be done before the migration can set that foreign key to be non-nullable).

However, it's possible for a product name not to match any product. In this case, I would like to flag this as an error with a message that the user must first add the missing product.

Questions:

1. It doesn't appear that `MigrationBuilder.Sql()` can return query results in order for me to check for unknown product names. Is there any way to perform such a check from a migration?
2. If I *could* check for unknown product names, can I just throw an exception? Do migrations recover gracefully from exceptions?
3. Has anyone does stuff like this, and do they have a better approach?

Comment: I think that's beyond the scope of automated migration, and you need to do that manually before making the changes.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu: Maybe. But I can run SQL and make those database changes just fine. Seems like performing a simple check and then throwing an exception wouldn't be hard.

Comment: I wasn't worried much about throwing an exception while migrating, but more about recovering from an error. DDL statements certainly can't be put in a transaction.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu: Those data migrations don't run within a transaction? Anyway, that is certainly an example of the type of problems I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I thought no DB supported transactional DDL. But since you asked, I checked, and apparently PGSQL and SQL Server, and even newer versions of MySQL do? I'm surprised actually. Maybe they do run in a transaction, so disregard my comment.

Comment: Yep, you guessed correctly, from MS docs: In most cases, EF Core will automatically wrap each migration in its own transaction when applying migrations. Unfortunately, some migrations operations cannot be performed within a transaction in some databases; for these cases, you may opt out of the transaction by passing suppressTransaction: true to migrationBuilder.Sql.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu: Well that's good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this, I see what I would like to do does not make a whole lot of sense.

All that the `Up()` and `Down()` methods do is configure the SQL update script that is about to be generated.

So `MigrationBuilder.Sql()` does not run immediately. It simply defines SQL to be added to the script. That's why this method cannot return results.

It's possible for the resulting script to be run on multiple databases (with different data states and validity). So performing checks while generates the script doesn't make a whole lot of sense.